# onChange validator regex function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to validate an onchange but can't seem to get it working.

Essentially, I want to test that if the input matches the regex then we present a message under the input.

I am unsure where to put the validator, I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction

Here is a sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-hooks-gni5jy?file=/src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
  // const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

  // const validator = (value) => {
  //   if (!value) return false;
  //   const re = /\b\d{5}\b/g;
  //   return re.test(value.trim());
  // };

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNumber(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={number || ""} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
      {/* {isValid ? <p>is valid</p> : null} */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the state inside the validator

```
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

  const validator = (value) => {
    if (!value) return false;
    const re = /\b\d{5}\b/g;
    const valid = re.test(value);
    setIsValid(valid);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNumber(value);
    validator(value);
  };
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-moon-k1xlsd?file=/src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js:114-443)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to call the validator for it to work.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);

  const validator = (value) => {
    if (!value) return false;
    const re = /\b\d{5}\b/g;
    return re.test(value.trim());
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNumber(value);
    setIsValid(validator(value)); // Validating the input
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={number || ""} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
      {isValid ? <p>is valid</p> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```